# Sound muted and locked but still working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Just reinstalled ubuntu 14.04 on this computer.

The sound is working perfectly in every application but it seems i don't have control from the desktop. I do have full controm from alsamixer.

Top right icon is here but muted and locked :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17MWO.png)

I have no output or input in sound settings : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3vFH.png)

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks